# Anchor link action networking in org chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating org chart using https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart

i am using this org chart http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/orgchart/tutorial/basic-interaction

I want a  anchor link in each node when the user click on it should go to that link but its not working it only collapse to sub child if i click on each node.

[image]

here's mycode

```
<script>
function test1()
{

alert('test prompt');
}

</script>
    <ul id="basic-interaction" class="hide">
        <li>
            <em>Batman<button onclick="test1()">test</button></em>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Batman Begins<br>
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ra's Al Ghul</li>
                        <li>Carmine Falconi</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    The Dark Knight<br>
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Joker</li>
                        <li>Two Face</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    The Dark Knight Rises<br>
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-one.png">
                    <img class="star" src="assets/images/tutorial/star-half.png">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bane</li>
                        <li>Talia Al Ghul</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Use an a tag instead of a button. That works for me.

Comment: are you saying anchor tag?

Comment: yes. `<a href="#">link</a>`. And there is a parameter called `nodeClicked` http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/orgchart/tutorial/node-clicks

Comment: but i need collapse too for anchor should go to link and when i click on node it should collapse is it possible?

Comment: Good to hear! You're welcome ;)